# vim turn off auto indent for README and text files

Tags: vim

When I open a README file in vim and start typing, I notice that whenever I hit enter, it automatically adds an indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing the below snippet into your .vimrc will turn off automatic text formating for files which both have any or no specific extension (the asterisk in the line), and do not have any specific syntax set (the `&syntax == ''` expression).

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &syntax == '' | set paste | endif
```

This is the same effect as doing :set paste in the vim console which turns off the automatic text formating which can sometimes get in the way of things.

Answer (score 0):

No. You are using a jackhammer to drill a pinhole.

You want to disable the `'autoindent'` option on `README` files but:

- `*` is going to match *every* file (hence your conditional on `&syntax`),
- `set paste` does a lot of ugly things besides resetting `'autoindent'`.

Here is a better solution:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead README set noautoindent
```

It works only on `README` files and acts *only* on the option you dislike. If it's not enough, you can also play with `'formatoptions'`. Basically, your solution is too broad: you must make it more specific.

Comment: That solution doesn't fix automatic indentation for paragraphs proceeding lines ending in colons, and also wont apply to similar text files such as those named 'readme' and 'READMEFIRST'.  You have 26k, do you really need to be using downvote on ppl with less than 100 points who themselves can't even use downvote due to insufficient points?